# What is Entity[x]?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://bdcampbell.net/javascript/book/javascript_the_good_parts.pdf)

Author  has a closure function:

```
return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
 function (a, b) {
 var r = entity[b];
 return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
 }
```

I'm not sure what function ENTITY is.

Comment: What page of the book are you seeing this code on?

Comment: It isn't defined in that section of code, and probably isn't a function.

Comment: It's a way to access something at a particular index, be it in strings, objects, arrays etc.

Comment: it could be entity array

Answer (score 0):

There is no such keyword in JavaScript, at least until ECMAScript7 (current). The only objects on which you can use these type of brackets `[]` is some kind of data structure (object, array, etc.). So this action `entyty[b]`will fetch the data which is represented by the key `b` inside the structure `entity`.

In this particular example, the value of `b` will represent all matched sub strings for the regular expression in the parenthesis `([^&;]+)` (check out why in the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) which will have structure `&something;` which is what a regular HTML entity looks like. For instance it could be `&gt;` which is the HTML entity for `>` etc.

So what the author actually means is:

```
var entity = {
   'gt': '>',
   'lt': '<',
   // other HTML entities mapping
};
var str = "&gt;&lt;&period;";
str = str.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
 function (a, b) {
    var r = entity[b];

    return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a; // checks if the entity existed in your entity collection, otherwise return the original string
 });
console.log(str);
```

The result will be: `><&period;`. Because you do not have `&period;` inside `entity`.

So the author represented an algorithm to transform HTML entities string to a string with their real character representations. You may develop further with this resource : https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Cheers!

Comment: Basically you can use `[]` (property accessors) on any object or object-coercible value.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, If you read my answer carefully, you will notice I pointed that out.